# PHP: What does &$this mean?

Tags: php, reference

As I was revieweing PHP sources to find the deprecated call-time-references, I found following 2 things in 3rd party code:

```
#1
$x = array(&$this, $a, $b);

#2
&$this->foo();
```

I know that `&` is meant for marking references. But it makes no sense to me.

In re. #1: When I use `array($this)` , won't there be a reference saved in the array, too?

In re. #2: When I call foo() of my own instance, why do I need to use `$this` as reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the code came from PHP4 time.

re #1 - In PHP 4 using  `array($this)` means the same as `array(clone($this))` in PHP 5. that is you get a copy of an object instead. In most cases you would like to get the same object though, not its copy. So I suppose the original author used `array(&$this)` exactly for that reason.

re #2 is explained in [Returning References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) chapter of the manual

in this case it it doesn't matter if it's `&$this` or some `&$obj`. The reference in fact is applied to the value returned from `foo()`. This might make sense for example if `foo()` has some big `static $cache` object inside and returns part of it back. E.g.

```
class MyClass {
  function &foo($id){
    static $cache;
    if (!isset($cache[$id])) {
      $cache[$id] = extract_some_object_from_database($id);
    }
    return $cache[$id];
  }
}
```

Notice the "&foo"

Comment: Thank you very much for you very much for your explanation! In re. #2, my mind has probably tricked me. I thought I have seen `&$this->bar()` somewhere, but I when I tried it, it gives a syntax error (also since it makes no sense). So it was probably a `$foo = &$this->bar()` I had seen. But this raises a warning in PHP 5.4: `Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference` , so I assume this technique will be deprecated soon?

Comment: The technique is ok, you can safely use it. I couldn't reproduce this Strict message unfortunately. As a guess try to check the code of bar(). If it has something like `return ($a+$b)` - that could be a problem. Example: https://eval.in/224995 . But if all return statements inside bar() return objects, you can remove & entirely.

Comment: Hm... maybe I still haven't understood it correctly. Here is my example code: https://eval.in/225027 . In PHP 5.4, I get this "Strict Standards" warning. I think $x and $foo->abc should be pointing at the same memory location now.

Comment: Ok, I understood you. In this case I think it is PHP's fault as it doesn't explain you your error. What PHP means is that you defined `bar()` as returning a value:`function bar() {...}`. So in your example it returns NULL, that means that when you wrote `$x = &$foo->bar()` PHP translated it to `$x = &NULL`. This doesn't make a lot of sense. What you should do (I think) in this case is to define `bar` as `function &bar() {...}` this way you tell that bar returns a variable that stores NULL and PHP will translate `$x = &$foo->bar()` into `$x = &$var_that_stores_NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a workaround for **pass by reference** in PHP

We have reference for the usage in PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "workaround"? The OP already knows that the & indicates a reference, but is asking why it is used in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

As @cs1193 is passing current object by reference. But now it has no sense because by default objects are passed by reference. So you create reference to reference.

```
$x = array(&$this, $a, $b); // this would be passing reference to reference on current object.

&$this->foo(); //makes pretty no sense. $this is already reference to current object.
```

In second example you need to call to method via $this because PHP don't know if you want to call class method or a function.

Comment: "by default objects are passed by reference" - there is an important difference between object references and variable references. When an object is passed by value (object reference), you can modify the properties of that object, but you cannot replace it with a competely different object or value. So passing a variable which contains an object by reference is still useful sometimes, just less often, because normally modifying the object in-place is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass value to function either by pass by value or pass by reference.in passby vaue new copy of varaible is created in memory where as in refrence just memory address is copied.in php & refers to pass by reference.